# How much important is it to develop different database specific escaping mechanisms for different projects?

Tags: php, mysql

As we know, the magic quotes in PHP is already deprecated, this is done to discourage relying on this feature for preventing SQL Injection and to encourage developers to develop database specific escaping mechanisms.[Source: php.net] Is this really neccessary?

If Yes,

Why? Why can't we just use functions like `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `addslashes()` and `stripslashes()` to achieve the same thing instead of developing a different escaping mechanisms?

An answer with example will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Pay attention to the "database specific" part. Not all DB's behave the same way.

Comment: I have modified my question, to reflect my actual query? Please review

Comment: my answer remains unchanged. `mysql_real_escape_string()` is mySQL specific. Other databases may need other methods of escaping data. Modern database layers like PDO do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` already is a database specific escaping mechanism :)

If you are choosing a database layer for a new project, be sure to take a look at [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) whose prepared statements will automatically take care of any necessary escaping.